# jQuery Carousel Problems

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey I am making a jQuery carousel and I have an issue. The images are displayed in a box and as one slides out the new slides in. Currently I only have 4 images that display, mainly because if I add one more all of the images show instead of just one. I have the height and width at 480px by 280px, not because I want them at that height and width, but because if I change the height or width by 1px then the same thing happens as above.

I want to be able to add as many images as I can, and also I want to be able to change the height and width to a larger pixel size. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="javaCode.js"></script>
<title>TITLE</title>
<head> <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
 href="image.png" />
</head>
<style>
body
{
background-image:url('background.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style>
<div id="carousel">
<ul>
    <li><img src="image1.jpg" alt="img1" id="img1" class="=img1"/></li>
    <li><img src="image2.jpg" alt="img2" id="img1" class="img1"/></li>
    <li><img src="image3.jpg" alt="img3" id="img1" class="img1"/></li>
    <li><img src="image4.jpg" alt="img4" id="img1" class="img1"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo1{
 width: 900px;
 height: 275px;
 margin-left: 525px;
 margin-right: auto; 
}
.AC1{
width:480px;
height:280px;

}
#carousel {
    width: 480px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel ul {
    width: 1920px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#carousel ul li {
    width:480px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 280px;
    list-style: none;
    float:  left;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Set the interval to be 5 seconds
var t = setInterval(function(){
    $("#carousel ul").animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
        $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    })
},5000);
```

});

***P.S. I'm trying to avoid using Plugins. I've had some bad experiences with them in the past. Thanks for the help.***

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to restrict the width of carousel ul

```
#carousel ul {
width: 1920px;
```

so when 4 images are there it is able to render properly as 480 x 4 = 1920, as soon as you add 5th image the width exceed and it shows at bottom of 1st image.

You can have a look at this for jquery/javascript carousel

[How to implement carousel effect using jQuery/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038155/how-to-implement-carousel-effect-using-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing may be bacause of the class value assigned for the first image tag.

```
<li><img src="image1.jpg" alt="img1" id="img1" class="**=img1**"/></li>
```